# How to Display Images from Assets - Image Name from CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, android-cursoradapter

have db with `_id,hName,lName,detail,images`

images stored in assets

images name in db (`SQLite`)

list layout without images working fine, but with images layout display's on names not images (no error in logcat)

wanted to bind `CursorAdpater` with `ImageView'

```
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView hName =  view.findViewById(R.id.hName);
        hName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hName")));

        TextView lName =  view.findViewById(R.id.lName);
        lName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lName")));

        ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        InputStream is = null;
        try {

            is = context.getAssets().open("birds/" + cursor.getColumnIndex("images"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="24dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="About" />
```

Comment: Compare how you're retrieving the `hName` and `lName` columns' values to how you're handling the `images` column. I.e.,  `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hName"))` versus `cursor.getColumnIndex("images")`.

Comment: wooo, worked thanks @Mike

Comment: but another  issue occurred , image taking entire area, so made changes in layout

`android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"`

got name but not images

Answer (score 0):

check the image `extension` is used in database 
then try this

```
try {
         is = context.getAssets().open("birds/" + cursor.getColumnIndex("images"));
         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
         image.setImageDrawable(d);

    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks but , work is done... don't know the problem but after rebuild project image start displaying